# Telegram API: answerCallbackQuery's "text" is not optional? (documentation states it is)

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I seems that `"text"` argument of the `answerCallbackQuery` API request is not optional, even though the documentation [states it is](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery):

> Text  String  Optional    Text of the notification. If not specified,
>   nothing will be shown to the user, 0-200 characters

It also [says](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery):

> **NOTE**: After the user presses a callback button, Telegram clients will
>   display a progress bar until you call answerCallbackQuery. It is,
>   therefore, necessary to react by calling answerCallbackQuery even if
>   no notification to the user is needed (e.g., without specifying any of
>   the optional parameters)

That is exactly what I'm trying to do, but alas I receive the error `"Bad Request: MESSAGE_EMPTY"` if `"text"` property is omitted. I can't believe that I'm the only one who has stumbled over this problem. Therefore I strongly suspect that I'm doing something wrong here. Can you please help?

I don't want notification to be shown on click because the reaction to click is going to be sent as the message, briefly after the click. Also it seems that other bots have no such problem, for example the *BotFather*.

Also, does anyone know a forum or another place where I can get a support regarding the API?

Comment: Sorry for I can't reproduced this problem, maybe temporary server-side problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was a temporary bug that was fixed in the same day.

Thanks to **Sean** for advising [@BotTalk](https://t.me/BotTalk) where problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is **optional** for `text` parameter yet.

I tried [this request](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?answerCallbackQuery-1d8aef8d), and no error shown.

You can join [@BotTalk](https://t.me/BotTalk) group which is created by Telegram Support Force, and ask if others have same problem.

Comment: You know what, you have solved my problem! It seems that adding `show_alert` helped. But why? it is optional, same as `text` and docs do not say that either of them must be specified.

Comment: And, by any chance do you know what *alert* is?

Comment: Alert will show pop-up instead of banner, and this should be optional too 

Comment: No pop-up shows up. So it seems like a bug because it should not be needed.